# Changing reputation with New Game Plus

Tags: mass-effect-3

I finished ME3 a few days ago and want to play through New Game+. [I read here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53623/is-there-a-new-game-plus-for-mass-effect-3):

> You'll retain your level, powers, and bonus powers, your credits, your
>   **Reputation/Renegade/Paragon scores**, and all weapons, mods and armor.

I played Paragon the first time through, but now I want to play 100% renegade, just for the fun of it (sick of always being a goodie-goodie two-shoes).

Is it possible to play 100% renegade (and thus unlock the renegade option in final confrontation) with New Game Plus? Or do I need to start fresh/re-import my ME2 save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be 100% renegade, then you'll need to start a whole new game.

Starting a new game+ will allow you to increase your renegade score though. See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57361/does-filling-your-reputation-bar-with-paragon-prevent-you-from-filling-it-with-r/57365#57365).

As a side note, you don't need 100% renegade to unlock the renegade option in the final confrontation, you must meet other requirements detailed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55186/how-do-you-get-the-last-paragon-renegade-dialogue-option-towards-the-end-of-the) and [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/what-does-100-paragon-or-100-renegade-actually-mean).